# I am getting some errors in installing go tools for vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup my visual studio code for go language. but i am getting some errors in installing gopls and go-outline.

errors

```
Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline@latest FAILED
    {
     "killed": false,
     "code": 1,
     "signal": null,
     "cmd": "C:\\Program Files\\Go\\bin\\go.exe install -v github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline@latest",
     "stdout": "",
     "stderr": "C:\\Users\\harsh\\go\\pkg\\mod\\github.com\\ramya-rao-a\\go-outline@v0.0.0-20210608161538-9736a4bde949\\main.go:14:2: read C:\\Users\\harsh\\go\\pkg\\mod\\golang.org\\x\\tools@v0.1.1\\go\\buildutil\\allpackages.go: unexpected NUL in input\n"
    }

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "C:\\Program Files\\Go\\bin\\go.exe install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.1.11-0.20220407163324-91bcfb1bdf9c\nverifying github.com/sergi/go-diff@v1.1.0: zip: not a valid zip file\n"
}
```

the screenshot of the errors.

Is there any other way to install this tools ?

Comment: need more info, e.g. what go version, are you using go modules, what env vars have you set

Comment: In particular, can you share `go.exe env` output? And please try to run `go.exe clean -modcache` and run tool installation command again? If it doesn't work, can you run `go.exe install -v -x  golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest` and share the error output?

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
 go env -w GO111MODULE=on
```

and

```
go clean -modcache
```

and install again.